# Db's data is continuously piling up in hits

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mariadb, logstash

I am making search function by linking Mariadb with elasticsearch and logstash.

By the way..

By the way, every time I get a value from logsdbash's mariadb, that value is accumulated in the hit of elasticsearch.

I want to know what's wrong

**elasticsearch.yml**

```
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------
  cluster.name: nov-cluster
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------
  node.name: nov-node1
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------
  network.host: 0.0.0.0
  http.port: 9200
```

**logstash.conf**

```
input {
  stdin { }
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/local/logstash/lib/mariadb-java- 
    client-2.4.3.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => 
    "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/Novtree_ShoppingMall?user=root"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM products"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "novtree_shoppingmall"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

**nodeJS**

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { body } = await esClient.search({
      index: 'novtree_shoppingmall',
      body: {
        query: {
          multi_match : {
            query: req.body.search,
            fields: [ 'title', 'content' ],
            minimum_should_match: 3,
          }
        }
      }
    })
    res.render('index', {
      hits: body.hits.hits,
      nonUser: req.nonUser
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
});
```

**logstash**

I'm getting data from the products table every minute

[logstash result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNS8i.png)

**elasticsearch**

Whenever logstash gets data from the products table every minute, it accumulates in hits.

[elasticsearch result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQXNK.png)

Comment: What value is "accumulated"?

Comment: By the schedule set in the input of logstash.conf, every time the data is updated in the db, it keeps accumulating on hits.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is very unclear. I don't quite understand what you mean with "accumulating on hits". If I had to guess though, maybe you need to set a tracking columen for logstash `input {
  jdbc {
    statement => "SELECT id, mycolumn1, mycolumn2 FROM my_table WHERE id > :sql_last_value"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => "id"
    # ... other configuration bits
  }
}` or maybe you need to decide on an ID column for elastic so your product get updated and not added indefinitely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that once a minute logstash fetches the aaaa / sunglass / alanmikle row from the product database, then inserts that into elasticsearch. The same row of the database will get duplicated once each minute, over and over again. There are two approaches to fixing this.

Firstly, you can use the [fingerprint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-fingerprint.html) filter to generate a unique id for the row, and set that as the [document_id](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_id) option on the elasticsearch output. This will result in the row being fetched and overwriten once a minute. This is very inefficient, but gives the result you want.

Secondly, if the database contains a column that is either a sequence or a timestamp that can be used to identify new rows, then you can use the [state](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_state) management feature of the jdbc plugin, which will persist the value of that column as :sql_last_value to be used in a WHERE clause that only fetches new rows.